# Is there anything to do with a loud banging electric cove heater?

Tags: heater

I bought a house with one of those expensive and "efficient" radiant cover heaters in the masters bedroom. It's electric. However, it is so loud when heating up (or cooling down) with metal expansion that it prevents us from sleeping. It's like someone is banging on the heater with a spoon every 2 seconds!

Video/audio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWBfQ0NAKBw

Is my heater garbage or it can be arranged? Any recommandations on that particular case?

Thank you very much.

Comment: find out what's slipping, likely something around a screw or clip. Try to tighten it so it doesn't move anymore. If that doesn't work, loosen it a bit and grease it so that it can move, but smoothly and quietly.